# Restoring/importing innodb database directories

Tags: mysql

I recently reinstalled mysql. Forgetting I still had data I wanted, I deleted all the data files as well without doing a mysqldump.

I have a backup of the raw database data directories which were located in in /usr/local/var/mysql/*. I restored the directories but not sure what to do next. Been googling around but no luck finding a clear answer.

Comment: Move the Question to dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Install the same version of MySQL server, then stop MySQL, copy raw data files to MySQL datadir location and start MySQL again. You should be able to access your data now.

But...

Did you make this backup when your MySQL was stopped? If not, there is a fair chance DB files could be corrupted and thus unable to be successfuly recovered.

Comment: Yes. MySQL server was stopped.

I'm not sure what version of MySQL I had previously. I had it installed with Homebrew (on a Mac) probably about 1 year ago. My current version of MySQL was also installed with Homebrew.